# CSRF Token Mismatch | Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

Whenever I send a POST request to server, TokenMismatchException error comes. I have already tried sending

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value= "{{csrf_token()}}">
```

Earlier, I was using ajaxHeader to send this particular piece of information to server but that is also throwing same error.

I have debugged more and find out that in VerifyCsrfToken file.

```
protected function tokensMatch($request)
    {
        $token = $this->getTokenFromRequest($request);
        return is_string($request->session()->token()) &&
               is_string($token) &&
               hash_equals($request->session()->token(), $token);
    } 

array:3 [
 "sessionToken" => "rgicYLOUhb2kLLChpVByNLQO1KVMb0Gkjzb7ZtTN" //$request->session()->token()
 "requestToken" => "IgXWquvnfujZJ1Vs9vbSgpjgX3rAnd5PpeklRvBD"  // $request->input('_token') ?: $request->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN')
 "laravel_token" => "rgicYLOUhb2kLLChpVByNLQO1KVMb0Gkjzb7ZtTN" //csrf_token()
]
```

I am getting above array in middleware token match function. Can anybody please tell me the reason and solution of this particular problem ? 
Below is the ajax I am using

```
function likeReview(id)
    {
        var like_span = $('#like_'+id);
        var like_div  = $('#likeDiv_'+id);
        var like_span_text = $('#likeText_'+id);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '{{route('like.review')}}',
            data: {review_id: id},
            beforeSend: function () {
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.status == 'success')
                {
                    var like = like_span.html();
                    var sum  = 0;
                    if(data.like == 1){
                        sum = parseInt(like)+1;
                        like_div.addClass('upvoted-active');
                        like_span_text.html('UPVOTED');
                    } else {
                        sum = parseInt(like)-1;
                        like_div.removeClass('upvoted-active');
                        like_span_text.html('UPVOTE');
                    }
                    like_span.html(sum);
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
                alert('Something went wrong. Please try again!');
            }
        });
    }
```

Function is called on click of upvote button

```
<div class="js-btn-thank-area upvoted-active js-activity-root" id="likeDiv_{{$review->id}}">
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="likeReview({{$review->id}})" class="thank-btn">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up fa-fw"></i>
    <span class="feed-action-text" id="likeText_{{$review->id}}">UPVOTED</span>
   </a>
   <div class="stats-thanks" id="like_{{$review->id}}">                                                                    
    {{$review->likes()->where('like','=',1)->count()}}
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: post your code. how do you send data ?

Comment: Post the form submit and ajax code where you are facing the problem ?

Comment: Have you looked through https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: are you using a form for posting it?

Comment: Nigel Ren - I have already went through documentation
Yes, Somewhere I am using form otherwise I have just use onclick to call the ajax - Exprator

Comment: It looks like the Ajax call doesn't use a form at all.  You may want to include the csrf_token in the data section.  Can you check what it actually posted and to where?  You can use the developer tools network console.

Comment: Above example isn't showing a form, if you want I can post form also. Already checked and double checked. So if you have any ideas other than that please help   - mrjink

Comment: I meant to say that Ajax doesn't use the form but does its own post.  I think you need to change `data: {review_id: id},` to `data: {review_id: id, _token: {{ csrf_token() }}},`. Nigel's answer should work, too.

Comment: I have tried it and it's not working - mrjink

Comment: @Shwetank the javascript code you've posted, is it in a separate file or in the view?

Comment: It is in a seperate footer_js file which I am including in every view. @DouwedeHaan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Just using CSRF as a field for posting with AJAX does not work;</s>

```
$.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'csrftoken' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' } });
```

Before you make the ajax call set it up :)!

**EDIT**: You can also put in the data part of your ajax request;

```
data: {
    review_id: id,
    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
}
```

**EDIT**: To clarify clearing temporary data from `storage` solved this issue in chat.

Comment: Already tried both of the way you mentioned it's still not working.

Comment: Did you remove the csrf token from the html form?

Comment: I didn't get you can you be more specific ?

Comment: remove this: `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value= "{{csrf_token()}}">` then use one of my changes and print out response if you still have issues.

Comment: Yes, I have already tried it. I am still facing same error. - Robert Pounder

Comment: can you delete everything in storage/sessions and storage/views and storage/cache but keep the folders, if its still not working tell me a time best for you to stackoverflow chat (in BST)

Comment: It's not working already tried that, if you are free right now we could chat. - Robert Pounder

Comment: I don't have enough point to chat. I am working on it. My colleague is on the chat reply him